# Symfony - Doctrine - Select query with a user (but can be anonymous user)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony 3, and I'm storing some data to database.
For this, the user does not have to be logged in.

Now I've created a select query with `$this->getUser();`. But the User can be NULL. When I execute this query, it does not select any rows.

`return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->where('product.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('product.product = :product')
        ->andWhere('product.cartId = :uniqueCartId')
        ->setParameters([
            'product' => $product,
            'user' => $user,
            'uniqueCartId' => $uniqueCartId
        ])
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();`

`$user = $this->getUser();`

I already tried this:
`if(!$user instanceof User) $user = NULL;`
But that does not work.

If I remove the User check, it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should bind the where clause if there is an user object like

```
$parameters=array(
    'product' => $product,
    'uniqueCartId' => $uniqueCartId
);
$user = $this->getUser();
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->where('product.product = :product')
        ->andWhere('product.cartId = :uniqueCartId');
if($user != null){  /* if($user instanceof User) */
    $parameters['user'] = $user;
    $query = $query->andWhere('product.user = :user');
}else{
    /* $query = $query->andWhere('product.user IS NULL'); Not necessary */
}
$query->setParameters($parameters)
      ->getQuery()
      ->execute();
```